# Using stored procedures to group a table

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures

**UPDATE** - I have figured out how to add the stored procedures using code-first migration. 'All' I am wondering now is how I can apply a `SELECT * FROM _tempTable1_ UNION SELECT * FROM _tempTable2`, and then output this. I was thinking of implementing a third stored procedure which does this but I am not  sure whether this is the right thing to do? Much appreciated help:)

I have a table connected to my ASP.NET MVC application, and I have created two stored procedures in SQL Server. Is it possible to implement these stored procedures in a way so that when the table is output, it can be grouped into these stored procedures?

MetBasicCriteria

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[MetBasicCriteria]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    SELECT * 
    FROM dbo.Applications
    WHERE NorwegianCitizen=1 
    AND CurrentlyInUni=1
    AND Norwegian=1
    AND English=1
END
```

MetMoreCriteria

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[MetMoreCriteria] 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    --EXEC [dbo.MetBasicCriteria]

    SELECT * 
    FROM dbo.Applications
    WHERE (Dutch=1
    OR OtherCitizenships='Dutch'
    OR (Course_bachelor='Political Science' OR Course_bachelor='Economy' OR Course_bachelor='International Relations')
    OR (Grade_Bachelor='a' OR Grade_Bachelor='A' OR Grade_Bachelor='b' OR Grade_Bachelor='B'))
    --AND MetBasicCriteria=1
END
```

**In other words** --> *can I use say 3 different stored procedures, save the outcomes of these 3 into different temporary tables, and the using `UNION ALL` combine them into 1 temporary table?*

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using entity framework?

Comment: Yes I am, ASP.NET MVC with EF 6

Comment: Code first or database first?

Comment: Your 2nd procedure executes the first procedure. If you want a **single** resultset from the 2nd procedure, you will need to insert the resultset from the first procedure into a table of some type and then logically join that table with the resultset of the query that follows in the second. You could simply insert it into the same table. You could "join" them using UNION ALL (or UNION depending on your goal). You could also join the rows if needed. Think about duplicates. Consider combining the logic into 2 procedures.

Comment: Code first with migrations

Comment: @SMor  so the second procedure is sortof an extension of the first one, where they have to return 'true' for the first procedure in order to 'qualify' for the second. There are also going to be some that dont meet the criteria of the first procedure, will your suggestion still be the case then?

Comment: @SMor, I see what you mean. So I would call the procedures on the data, and using a temporary table to store the result of the queries, add them together (also with the records that did not meet even the standard criteria) and then output this, which will present the table as if it was grouped by the procedures, i.e. something among the lines of: `SELECT * FROM temp_table1 UNION SELECT * FROM temp_table2 UNION SELECT * FROM temp_table3`, where `temp_table3` is the one with all the records which have not been selected through the 2 stored procedures?

Comment: No one but you understands your system design. Nor do your procedure names give any clues about what the set of rows produced represent. They seem to do very similar things so combining the logic might be a good idea. But only you can really answer that. Your logic gives a sense that your system design is a little too flexible. You should not need to compare both upper and lower case letters for grades - that column should be constrained. I see room for many improvements. Try both approaches is my suggestion.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, I am aware that there is indeed room for a lot of improvements. I will try it out.

Comment: @SMor, I have been trying about a bit, and I am not really getting to where I need. I thought about creating 3 different stored procedures, where I select all records based off different criteria and store these into global temporary tables. However, I found that doing so I cannot union the tables, as they will not have 'an equal number of expressions in their target lists'. Could you help me out with this maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just take your second procedure code and modify it as a simple POC. I have no idea how you intend to merge or alter or combine the resultsets from your first procedure with that of your second procedure. So I leave that for you. I will also remove the meaningless comments you leave in the code since you seem to be using some sort of template.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[MetMoreCriteria] 
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    create table #basic (
       id  int not null,
       ...
    );
    Insert #basic (id) --column list to be defined
    EXEC [dbo.MetBasicCriteria];

    SELECT appl.id, ...  
    FROM dbo.Applications as appl
    WHERE (appl.Dutch=1
       OR appl.OtherCitizenships='Dutch'
       OR (appl.Course_bachelor in ('Political Science', 'Economy', 'International Relations'))
       OR (appl.Grade_Bachelor in ('A', 'a', 'B', 'b'))
       )
    AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM #basic as basic where basic.id = appl.id)
    ORDER BY ...;
END
```

Hopefully I used the parentheses correctly but I can't test it and this edit widget does not auto-count or correct typos or mistakes. Some better coding points:

- define an alias for each table and use it for every column reference.
- don't use "*" generally as a column list
- Using IN rather than a series of logical OR comparisons makes your code more readable and less prone to error

The column list in the SELECT and INSERT statements should be specific - don't use the lazy asterisk to select all columns since you typically don't need them all. If you do need them all, then specify each column to avoid future problems if the schema of the tables changes. The only place where "*" is acceptable as a column list is inside an EXISTS clause.

I also added the ORDER BY clause since the consumer of a resultset usually wants those rows ordered. But perhaps your application/consumer does not care? If so, remove it and save some processor cycles.

Lastly this is just one approach. You could also make your first procedure a view or a UDF since it does nothing complicated. And that comment can also apply to this procedure. Perhaps you are just over-complicating a rather simple set of logic? NB that I omit any error-handling and leave that to you. And let me re-iterate that this is NOT a recommendation. Simply one implementation option.

Comment: Thank you for explaining it. You are right, I am overcomplicating it and I have found out now how to apply it to my code with your help, so thanks. I am very new to this so thank you for your patience I know it can be really annoying hehe

Comment: What would you recommend doing though? for future references I mean